# Prolog displaying a path

Tags: prolog

I have the following simple graph:

> x <---> y <---> z

```
edge(x,y).
edge(y,z).

path(Start,End,Path) :-           % path/3: there is a `Path` from `Start` to `End`
    path(Start,End,[Start],Path).

path(End,End,RPath,Path) :-       % internal helper predicate `path/4`
    reverse(RPath,Path).
path(Start,End,Visited,Path) :-
    edge(Start,Next),
    \+ memberchk(Next,Visited),
    path(Next,End,[Next|Visited],Path).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- path(x,z,P).
P = [x, y, z] ;                   % works as expected
false.

?- path(z,x,P).                        
false.                            % unexpectedly fails!
```

What can I do to make above query succeed?

Comment: reverse again. But why ?

Comment: So if i wanted to find if a path from z to x is possible. If i query this at I get nothing.

Comment: How would I do the above without using reverse and just vanilla prolog?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle an *undirected* graph:

```
path(Start, End, Visited, Path) :-
    ( edge(Start, Next) ; edge(Next, Start) ),
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

First, we write down the known facts by defining predicate `edge/2`:

```
edge(x,y).
edge(y,x).
edge(y,z).
edge(z,y).
```

Then we use `edge/2` in tandem with [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`path/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328433/definition-of-a-path-trail-walk) like so:

```
?- path(edge,Path,x,z).              % one direction
  Path = [x,y,z]
; false.

?- path(edge,Path,z,x).              % other direction
  Path = [z,y,x]
; false.
```

How about the following very general query? What are **all** possible paths based on `edge/2`?

```
?- path(edge,Path,From,To).
  From = To,         Path = [To]
; From = x , To = y, Path = [x,y]
; From = x , To = z, Path = [x,y,z]
; From = y , To = x, Path = [y,x]
; From = y , To = z, Path = [y,z]
; From = z , To = y, Path = [z,y]
; From = z , To = x, Path = [z,y,x]
; false.
```